# Unable to access data from Mongodb via express/mongoose/angularjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angularjs, express, mongoose

I am working on a simple custom CMS using the MEAN stack. 
This is my first web app ever, and I am using it to learn the ropes, as it were.
Unfortunately I am unable to access the data from the mongodb. The mongodb service is running, and the data is there (I inserted two news documents to a "news" collection from the mongo shell)
when I view it via db.news.find(). I added the sample data (two documents) with the 'db.news.insert( var )', since .

So what I need is to be able to fetch the news data from the db, and send it to the angular.js client, which will then display it in a fixed box on every route.
Then, of course, I need to be able to edit the data in the angular client, send it back to the server and save it to the db. Pretty basic stuff. I know that my angular code works fine, since when I use an actual object and bind it to a scope I can access and see the data. Here's how I try to access the db from angular:
I have annotated the code with comments describing all the problems I encountered.
Please pay attention to those marked <- and ^-. Cheers

```
angular.module('App', ['ngResource'])
    .controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, $resource){
        var News = $resource('/');
        var news = News.query();
        console.log(news); 
     // ^- No news logged in the console - sometimes I am getting an empty array,
     //    sometimes an 'undefined' and asometimes an array of approx. 2761 elements
     //    where each is a single character. Characters form patterns like this - 
     //    [{"0":"<"},{"0":"!"},{"0":"D"},{"0":"O"},{"0":"C"},{"0":"T"},{"0":"Y"},
     //    {"0":"P"},{"0":"E"},{"0":" "},{"0":"h"},{"0":"t"},{"0":"m"},{"0":"l"},
     //    {"0":">"},...]
     //    When all the characters are assembled they form '<!DOCTYPE html>' - 
     //    hmm... somewhat sounds familiar, but not what I expected. 
     //    The whole array appears to be the HTML of the very website encoded 
     //    in an array of objects character by character.

        $scope.news = news; // <- No data available in the scope, or displays the same array mentioned above.
        // $scope.news = news[0]; // <- No data available in the scope, or displays the same array mentioned above.
        // $scope.news = { // <- This puts the data in the scope just fine.
        //    headline: "Huseyin Ozer at Wimbledon",
        //    bd: "Wimbledon Championships arranged between 24th of June – 7th of July. I followed all the finals with pleasure. In women final Bartoli won the prize but Lisicki won everybody’ s heart with her outgoingness. With Andy Murray I shared the pride of British people.",
        //    imgURI: encodeURI("images/news/wimbledon.jpg"),
        //    imgThumbURI: encodeURI("images/news/thumbs/wimbledon.jpg"),
        //    imgCaption: "Wimbledon finals were amazing. I am sharing the pride of British people.",
        //    addedOn: new Date(),
        //    addedBy: "Admin"
        // }
    });
```

Here's the code for my webserver:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , fs = require('fs');

// Defining connection to the database:
var mongoose = require('mongoose').
    connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/huseyin-ozer"),
    db = mongoose.connection;
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectID = Schema.ObjectId;
// Setting up the debug flag:
mongoose.set('debug, true');
// Logging connection:
db
  .on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'DB connection error.'))
  .once('open', console.log.bind(console, 'DB Connection established.'));

// Defining MongoDB schemas:
var husOzSchema = new Schema({

});
var usr = new Schema({
    first: String,
    last: String
});
var newsSchema = new Schema({
    headline: String,
    bd: String,
    imgURI: String,
    imgThumbURI: String,
    imgCaption: String,
    addedOn: Date,
    addedBy: {
        type: ObjectID,
        ref: 'usr'
    }
//           {first: String,
//            last: String}
});
// On user action 'save' populate the addedOn and addedBy fields before the news article is actually saved to the DB:
newsSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    if( !this.addedOn ) this.addedOn = new Date();
    if( !this.addedBy ) this.addedBy = {first: "admin", last: "admin"};
});
// Indexing important fields:
usr.index({last: 1});
newsSchema.index({headline: 1});
//Adding the News model:
var News = mongoose.model('News', newsSchema);

//Creating and saving some test data to MongoDB:
//var nws1 = new News({
//    headline: "Huseyin Ozer at Wimbledon",
//    bd: "Wimbledon Championships arranged between 24th of June – 7th of July. I followed all the finals with pleasure. In women final Bartoli won the prize but Lisicki won everybody’ s heart with her outgoingness. With Andy Murray I shared the pride of British people.",
//    imgURI: encodeURI("images/news/wimbledon.jpg"),
//    imgThumbURI: encodeURI("images/news/thumbs/wimbledon.jpg"),
//    imgCaption: "Wimbledon finals were amazing. I am sharing the pride of British people.",
//    addedOn: new Date(),
//    addedBy: "Admin"
//});
//var nws2 = new News({
//    headline: "David Miliband’s Goodbye Party",
//    bd: "David Miliband choose his favourite restaurant from many alternatives. His goodbye party was held at OZER Restaurant before he will go to New York. On that night many of Labour Party deputies signed the book called ’ The History of Labour Party’ as a gift for Mr. Ozer.",
//    imgURI: encodeURI("images/news/DMGoodbye.jpg"),
//    imgThumbURI: encodeURI("images/news/thumbs/DMGoodbye.jpg"),
//    imgCaption: "Farewell party at Ozer.",
//    addedOn: new Date(),
//    addedBy: "Admin"
//    });
// For some reason upon running the server, the data is not stored in the DB using the code below. Why is that?
//nws1.save(function(err, news){
//        if(err) return console.error("Error while saving data to MongoDB: " + err); 
//                       ^- no error displayed in the console. All ok?...
//        console.dir(news); // <- ... not really. No data displayed in the console either.
//    });
//nws2.save(function(err, news){ // <- same as above
//            if(err) return console.error("Error while saving data to MongoDB: " + err);
//            console.dir(news);
//        });
var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'html')
    .engine('html', function(path, options, fn){
        if('finction' == typeof options){
            fn = options, options = {};
        }
        fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', fn);
    });
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
app.use(express.session());
//app.use(app.router); // <- When I uncomment this the website doesn't render at all. all I see is a couple of square brackets - '[]'

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); <- when I move this below the routes defined below, I am also getting a blank page with a pair of square brackets - '[]'
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    News.
        find().
        exec(function(err, nws){
            if(err) return next(err);
            res.send(nws);
//            res.render(nws);
        });
    res.render('index', { title: 'static Express' });
});
app.get('/users', user.list);

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html', {layout: null})
})

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I very much appreciate your help.
Regards,
Jared

Comment: Ignoring the client side, is the call to `News.find().exec` working as expected?

Comment: @WiredPrairie That I would like to know as well. How can I check it is working as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely will want to add a route specifically for the "news":

```
app.get('/news', function(req, res, next){
    News.
        find().
        exec(function(err, nws){
            if(err) { res.writeHead(500, err.message) } 
            else { 
                res.send(nws);
            }
        });
});
```

Right now, you've got it returning the basics of a web page (`res.render('index', { title: 'static Express' });`) and then the response from the `find` call. Angular won't accept that as a result, and it explains why you're seeing the DOCTYPE in the response.

And then call it from your Angular code:

```
var News = $resource('/news');
```

Comment: Thank you WiredPrairie. Yes, it works now. I can see how the (res.render('index', { title: 'static Express' });) messed things up. It was a line generated by WebStorm I missed out.

Comment: More importantly though, thanks my mistake and your answer I can now understand the relationship between angular routes and Express routes. Because before I understood the relationship very vaguely, I knew I would run into troubles because of that. I'm glad it happened sooner than later when my app scales up :). Thank you again for your time mate. Very much appreciated.